# wmz-host.ru

Tags: хостинг

Заказал я хостинг на вмз, сначала тестовый период, сегодня оплатил, потому что домен не работал(нужно было оплатить), значит оплатил я , а ссылка все ровно не работает, подскажите пожалуйста, что это может быть?

Comment: что значит "ссылка не работает" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно ещё не прописалась новая инфы на dns серверах. Вроде как надо около суток ждать, чтобы припаркованный домен заработал.

Comment: В особых случаях доходит до недели